# How to loop through color set and apply to "fill" in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

For [this](https://dsundell.studio.mcad.edu/prog-for-web/13-a/index.html) sketch, I wanted to have the stars have slightly different colors, to emulate how actual stars are not just pure white light. I tried a few different methods of doing this without any success. How would you accomplish this?

Looking to modify the first `fill(255)` to draw each star in a distinct color from a set. I tried using an array of around 4 colors and accessing the indexes. I tried using `random()` to choose rgb values a few numbers away from 255. I'm fairly new at this, so forgive my lack of proper terminology. I think I likely just didn't put my loop through the arrays in the correct spot.

Full code is [here](https://github.com/dani-sundell/prog-for-web/blob/61cb4e381bedd02344ffb1be39b0c77e5832e41b/13-a/sketch.js). Thanks in advance!

```js
function starsMoon() { //create star cluster and moon
  randomSeed(300);
  translate(-width * 2, -height * 2);
  noStroke();
  fill(255);
  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) { // stars
      // this is where I initially put the fill(colorSet[i])
      ellipse(random(0,width * 4) + i, random(0,height * 4) + i, 2, 2);
  }
  fill(255);
  ellipse(width * 1.25, height * 2, 100, 100); // moon
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah either of those would work!

Random offset:

```js
function starsMoon() { //create star cluster and moon
  randomSeed(300);
  translate(-width * 2, -height * 2);
  noStroke();
  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) { // stars
      fill(250 + ((random() - 0.5) * 2 * 5)) // random fill between 245 - 255
      ellipse(random(0,width * 4) + i, random(0,height * 4) + i, 2, 2);
  }
  fill(255);
  ellipse(width * 1.25, height * 2, 100, 100); // moon
}
```

To rotate through colors from a list you just need take the index mod the number of colors:

```js
function starsMoon() { //create star cluster and moon
  randomSeed(300);
  translate(-width * 2, -height * 2);
  noStroke();
  let colors = [
      color(210, 180, 170), 
      color(40, 100, 29), 
      color(100, 100, 110), 
      color(102, 210, 12)
  ]
  for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) { // stars
      fill(colors[i % colors.length])  // loop through colors
      ellipse(random(0,width * 4) + i, random(0,height * 4) + i, 2, 2);
  }
  fill(255);
  ellipse(width * 1.25, height * 2, 100, 100); // moon
}
```

Cool project btw!

Comment: This is perfect. I hadn't used remainder before so great to know more about that now as well. Thank you so much!